# scala test: verify using functions as parameters

Tags: scala, scalatest, verify

I am trying to use verify on a mocked object's method, where it receives two parameters, one of them a String and the other one a function. So basically in my test i have:

```
verify(mockedObj).someMethod(aString, theFunction _)
```

theFunction is defined in an object. The error I am getting is the following:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
mockedObj.someMethod(
    "theFunction",
    ($anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2) <function1>,
    TypeTag[String],
    TypeTag[String]
);
-> at  bla.TestClass$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(TestClass.scala:28)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
mockedObj.someMethod(
    "theFunction",
    (anonfun$someMethod$1) <function1>,
    TypeTag[String],
    TypeTag[String]
);
-> at bla.RealObject$.someMethod(RealObject.scala:17)
```

Any clues on how could I actually perform this?

Thanks!!

Comment: I would almost go out on a limb here to say that it's doing an equals comparison to the "theFunction" and thus failing the check.

Comment: Yes, I believe so, unless I am not referring exactly the same function defined in the same value, it will always fail. I will get around with something else to verify.